# How can I add 30 pixels to set amount per loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, addition

I'm making a chart that populates with user inputs but I need the loop to move the new legend items for each loop.

I am using simpleGraphics to do the image but on each loop drawing my chart I need the next item drawn to move down 30 pixels. Tried using a list but it wouldn't allow me that way.

```
    pieSlice(200,100,400,400,0,(globals()['itemValue%s' % x]))
    rect(650,130+(30),20,20)
    text(710,140+(30),(globals()['itemName%s' % x]))
```

I know +(30) is a set amount but it is just a placeholder until I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare a variable outside loop and update it inside loop to get desired result.

```
step_count = 30
```

Assumig this code is inside loop , you can use the step_count variable as follows:

```
pieSlice(200,100,400,400,0,(globals()['itemValue%s' % x]))
rect(650,130+step_count,20,20)
text(710,140+step_count,(globals()['itemName%s' % x]))
step_count += 30
```